# Cordova: getUserMedia() no longer works on insecure origins

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, getusermedia, quasar-framework

**THE SITUATION**

In my Cordova hybrid app (built with [Quasar](https://quasar-framework.org/) framework), I need to a add a video-call feature.

I need to use the function `getUserMedia()`.

Everything works fine while testing on localhost, but when testing on the device it doesn't work.

**THE ERROR:**

`[Deprecation] getUserMedia() no longer works on insecure origins. To use this feature, you should consider switching your application to a secure origin, such as HTTPS.`

Most probably this error is caused by the fact that Cordova doesn't run on https.

**ATTEMPTS:**

I have tried everything I could find on Google but nothing worked..

**Crosswalk:**

I have seen somebody suggesting to install the [crosswalk](https://github.com/crosswalk-project/cordova-plugin-crosswalk-webview) plugin. I have tried but nothing changed.

**Permissions:**

I have tried asking for permission using the [android-permissions](https://github.com/NeoLSN/cordova-plugin-android-permissions) plugin.

But when it prompt the request, despite clicking on the `ALLOW` button, the permission was set to `DENIED_ALWAYS`...

I have tried using the [diagnostic](https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-diagnostic-plugin) cordova plugin, but the result was the same

**THE QUESTION:**

How can I use `getUserMedia()` in a cordova app?

**EDIT - THE SOLUTION:**

@Andre solution is the correct solution to the question.

I was getting that error while running the app in a dev environment in my device. Quasar run my devServer on 192.168.0.18, that is not same as localhost, and thus not recognized as secure.

By setting `https: true` in the config, that issue was resolved.

After building the app, Cordova run on file://, and on the file:// protocol there is no insecure origin issue, as pointed out by @jcesarmobile in the comments.

I had still problems on build, but not related with this problem itself, but involving permissions, and I managed to resolve them using the `cordova-plugin-android-permissions` plugin.

Comment: cordova uses file:// to load the app, that should still work. So, how does your app url looks like? should be some quasar problem then

Comment: Yes the app is served on file:// - This is the full path: file:///android_asset/www/index.html#/Home

Comment: Strange, it should work over file protocol. You can try with cordova-plugin-ionic-webview, it can be configured to serve over https

Comment: Thanks @jcesarmobile you were right. On file:// protocol there is no insecure issue. I had still problems but because of permissions not properly setup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You can't.**

Using getUserMedia() is no longer supported over http:// (Unsecure Origin), It will work only over https:// (Secure Origin)

- **For development purpose**, localhost is treated as a secure origin over HTTP, so if you're able to run your server from localhost, you should be able to work on that server. That's why it works on your case using locahost.
- **For production purpose**, consider using HTTPS. You can get a free SSL certificate [using Let's encrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/).

With Quasar framework, you can use Webpack over HTTPS by editing your [quasar.conf.js](https://quasar-framework.org/guide/app-quasar.conf.js.html) file. [Here are allowed parameters](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#devserverhttps).

```
// quasar.conf.js
devServer: {
    https: true
}
```

It'll use a self signed certificate.

If you want to use your own certificate, use as following :

```
// quasar.conf.js
devServer: {
  https: {
      key: fs.readFileSync('/path/to/server.key'),
      cert: fs.readFileSync('/path/to/server.crt'),
      ca: fs.readFileSync('/path/to/ca.pem'),
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for replying @André. I know that getUserMedia() doesn't work on HTTP. The problem here is that I am not running on http or https, but that I need it to run in a cordova mobile app. I think that there must be a way to use getUserMedia() on a cordova app.

Comment: Are you trying to use getUserMedia through a webview, or within cordova itself ?

Comment: Through the webview

Comment: How is your webview loaded ?

Comment: I am not doing anything directly about it. it's handled by the framework (Quasar).

Comment: Actually unfortunately it works only on dev mode. After building the app doesn't work anymore.. Do you know how can I achieve the same in a production environment?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189538/discussion-between-andre-ds-and-francescomussi).

Comment: Your answer was the actual solution. Thanks! I had still issue on prod but because of something else.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone coming to this since cordova-ios@6.0.0 was released there is now an easier way to solve this on iOS devices that are on iOS 14.5 or higher

Adding the following to config.xml allows the webview to be treated as a securecontext:

```
<preference name="scheme" value="app" />
<preference name="hostname" value="localhost" />
```

Source: https://cordova.apache.org/announcements/2020/06/01/cordova-ios-release-6.0.0.html

I'm still searching for a solution on android that doesn't require a local webserver.